# Pass HTML variable to separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, html, bar-chart, morris.js

I have a dictionary (sent from a python class) called "sentiments" in my html file. The following:

```
{% if sentiments %}
    <p>{{sentiments}}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>none</p>
{%endif%}
```

Prints:

```
('very positive', 34)
('positive', 64)
('neutral', 44)
('negative', 11)
('very negative', 27)
```

So I know that much is working fine. In a seperate javascript file, I have a morris bar chart with hard-coded values as follows:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-chart',
    data: [
        { x: 'V. Pos', y: 10},
        { x: 'Pos', y: 20},
        { x: 'Neutral', y: 30},
        { x: 'Neg', y: 20},
        { x: 'V.Neg', y: 10},
    ],

    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y'],
    labels: ['# Tweets'],
    barColors: function (row, series, type) {
        console.log("--> "+row.label, series, type);
        if(row.label == "V. Pos") return "#3300FF";
        else if(row.label == "Pos") return "#6600FF";
        else if(row.label == "Neutral") return "#9900FF";
        else if(row.label == "Neg") return "#FF3333";
        else return "#ff0000";
    }
});
```

I am calling this script as follows:

```
<div class="bar"; style="float:left; width:50%;">
    <div id="bar-chart"></div>
    <script src="../static/barchart.js"></script>
</div>
```

I would like to pass my dictionary "sentiment" to this script and use the values in it to populate the chart, rather than the hard-coded values I have now. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using Flask to connect my python and html.

Answer (score 0):

You can transcribe the variable to JS by doing:

```html
<body>
  <script>
    var myData = JSON.parse('{{sentiments_str | safe}}')
  </script>
</body>
```

When rendering the page, make sure to pass in `sentiments` using `json.dumps`, like:

```
return render_template('page.html', sentiments_str=json.dumps(sentiments))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and now this line:

    var sentiments_dict = {{ sentiments_str }}

Is giving me the error: "Expression statement is not an assignment or call"

Comment: I made some changes, try those.